# Python - Compare rows of .csv file based on column conditions

Tags: python, pandas, csv

| PersonId | Age | Height |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 18 | 191 |
| 2 | 35 | 187 |
| 3 | 52 | 165 |
| 4 | 20 | 172 |
| 5 | 49 | 188 |
| 6 | 62 | 174 |

I have this .csv file. My task is to compare each row with all others, filter it based on the Age and Height Difference values and give the respective results.

The filters that I am about to use are the following:
  Filter (1): check if the age difference is smaller than 5, between all persons. 
Filter (2): If Filter (1) holds, then  check the height difference < 20 (only for the persons that Filter (1) holds, not generally)

Target: Print

```
ID_person 1, ID_Person_2,
Age_Diff,Height_Diff
```

I have tried to use itertools.combinations to access the columns.

Is there a nicer, easier or more pythonic way of doing such a thing?
Here is what I coded so far

```
        import pandas as pd
        import os
        import itertools
        from operator import itemgetter
        import math
        
        # assign and open dataset
        file = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/ages.csv"
        data = pd.read_csv(file, index_col="personId")
        
        pwd = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(os.path.dirname(file))
        trainData = pd.read_csv(os.path.basename(file))
        os.chdir(pwd)
        
        # displaying data 
        print("\nMy Data is:")
        print(data)
        
        
    # Since we do a pairwise comparison Age of 1st Person we check = a1, Age of 2nd Person we check = a2
    for a1,a2 in itertools.combinations(data['age'],2):
            if abs(a1-a2) < 5:
                new_data = (a1,a2, abs(a1-a2))
                #print(new_data)
                df1 = data.loc[(data['age'] == new_data[0])]
                new_df1 = df1.append(data.loc[(data['age'] == new_data[1])]) # Create a new dataframe of filtered ages
                print("my first dataframe filtered by age difference is \n",new_df1)
                # Access the new dataframe to check height differences
                # Since we do a pairwise comparison Height of 1st Person we check = h1, Height of 2nd Person we check = h2
                for h1,h2 in itertools.combinations(new_df1['height'],2): 
                    if abs(h1-h2) < 20:
                        new_data_h = (h1,h2,abs(h1-h2))
                        print(new_data_h)
                        df2 = data.loc[(data['height'] == new_data_h[0])]
                        new_df2 = df2.append(data.loc[(data['height'] == new_data_h[1])]) # Create a new dataframe of filtered heights
                        print("my second dataframe filtered by height difference is \n",new_df2)
```

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Please show us the code, that you have already.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new dataframe for selected ages and apply filter2

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import itertools

c = """
PersonId    Age Height
1   18  191
2   35  187
3   52  165
4   20  172
5   49  188
6   62  174
"""

data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(c), sep='    ', engine='python')
selected_data = pd.DataFrame(columns=["PersonId","Age","Height"])
for a1,a2 in itertools.combinations(data['Age'],2):
    if abs(a1-a2) < 5:
        selected_data = selected_data.append(data.loc[data['Age'] == a1])
        selected_data = selected_data.append(data.loc[data['Age'] == a2])
for h1,h2 in itertools.combinations(selected_data['Height'],2):
    if abs(h1-h2) < 20:
        new_data_h = (h1,h2,abs(h1-h2))
        print(new_data_h)
```

output :

```
(191, 172, 19)
(191, 188, 3)
(172, 165, 7)
(172, 188, 16)
```

I didn't do anything after filter2 but you could create a new dataframe or modify selected one.